# ¿Cómo se puede hacer para que cuando le seleccione dicho dato me llene unos inputs con sus respectivos datos <select>?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php  
$conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database");
$sentencia = "SELECT * FROM cliente  ";
$query = mysqli_query($conexion,$sentencia);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>COmo puedo hacer que cuando eljija el nombre del cliente me lo traiga de la base de datos y me lo coloque en el input</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
</head>
<body>      
    <center>
        <table width="280" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" border="0" bgcolor="#1E679A">
        <h1>Editar Cliente</h1>
            <form action="" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <br> <label>Nombre Del Cliente : </label>
                <select name="Clientes">
<?php 
while ($arreglo = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
{
?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $arreglo['NIT']?>"><?php echo $arreglo ['nombre_Cliente']?></option>
<?php 
} 
?>
                </select></br>
                <br> <label>NIT : </label>
                <input type="text" name="user" placeholder=" " required size="30" maxlength="30" style="margin-left: 8%" /><br/>
                <br> <label style="margin-left: -10%"> ¿Se realizan RIPS?  </label>
                <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="" required size="10" maxlength="15" style="margin-left: 3%" /><br/>
                <br><input type="submit" name="Modificar_Cliente" value ="Modificar" onclick="location='http://localhost/Aeroasistencia/Administracion/modificarCliente.php'" style="margin-right: 3%">
                <input type="submit" name="Nuevo_Cliente" value ="Nuevo" onclick="location='http://localhost/Aeroasistencia/Administracion/nuevoCliente.php'">
                <input type="submit" name="Eliminar_Cliente" value ="Eliminar" onclick="location='http://localhost/Aeroasistencia/Administracion/eliminarCliente.php'" style="margin-left: 3%"> 
                <input type="submit" value="Volver" onclick="location='http://localhost/Aeroasistencia/Administracion/administracion.php'" style="margin-left: 3%" />
            </form>
        </table>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: se usa ajax , con eso tu tomas el dato del cliente que quieres filtrar y lo envias al archivo que quieres procesar y el retorno llegara al success del ajax y con eseo puedes obtener los datos para insertalos en lo sinput

Comment: pero no conozco de ajax

Comment: busca ajax , con php y te salen un monton de ejemplos